# How do I make a git commit equal to the diff between my working tree and a branch?

Tags: git

Git can be a complicated and funny beast, and I have a habit of copy/pasting stack overflow answers without understanding how they work. The result is that I often find myself in a state where my working tree is fine, but my branch is so messed up that I dont want to figure out how to merge it back to main. It would look something like this:

```
A---B---C---D---Main
  \   *******************
    \ * Big pile o' git *---Good
      *******************
```

What I want to do here is take the good state I have and put it on top of main so I have a nice clean working tree:

```
A--B--C--D--Main+Good
```

Is there a way to take the diff between what I have on one branch and the head of another branch and make it a new commit on top of the first match.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your intention but does `git diff main good` do what you mean? Suppose your branch names are `main` and `good`.

Comment: If you are in the main branch, `git diff good` diffs your working tree against the `good` branch.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you have some project state at `Main`, but you are not satisfied with it. You have a different project state at `Good` that you want to have. So you want to have one commit on top of `Main` that turns the project state into the one which you have at `Good`.

Comment: @ixvs I like the state I have in good, but I like the history of main. `git diff` shows me the commit I want to make. I could `git diff main good` and then manually make each change it shows and commit that to main and have the state I want.

Comment: @j6t you got it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to squash the changes on your branch to one single commit, and try to play it back on top of `Main` :

```
# starting from branch Good :
git checkout Good

# (optional) use a temporary branch if you want :
git checkout -b wip

# two commands to squash everyting into one commit on top of A :
git reset --soft A
git commit

# you can now use 'git rebase' :
git rebase Main
```

---

I guess you want the above solution, however, since your question is specifically worded as "I want to take the state of Good and place use that as the new state for Main", here is one way to do exactly that :

```
# starting from branch Good :
git checkout Good

# use reset --soft :
git reset --soft Main
git commit
```

note that this will completely replace the content of `Main` with the content of `Good`, and somehow ignore the modifications brought in by commits `B--C--D--Main`

Comment: Keep in mind that after these operations (I mean the second part) branch `Main` does not change and branch `Good` points at the new commit on top of `Main`. The commits that `Good` have been before the operation are now not on any branch anymore and will be garbage collected eventually.